# Por que não consigo imprimir?

Tags: c, ponteiro

É um codigo simples (Estou praticando ponteiros)
Ele não esta imprimindo o resultado, o programa encerra... pq? ;-;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.1416

void calc_esfera(float R, float *area, float *volume);

int main(){
    float raio, *area, *volume;

    printf("Raio: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%f", &raio);

    calc_esfera(raio, area, volume);

    printf("Area: %.2f\n", *area);

    printf("Volume: %.2f", *volume);

}

void calc_esfera(float R, float *area, float *volume){

    *area = PI * pow(R, 2.0);
    *volume = 4 * PI * pow(R, 3.0);
}
```

Comment: não sei bem se tem erro, talvez o console esteja fechando quando encerra o processamento. Se você adicionar algo do tipo `scanf("%f", &raio);` após o último `printf`, não resolve??

Comment: Testei seu código e está funcionando: https://ideone.com/Nly6Qx  apenas atribui um valor para a variável `raio` pois o `scanf` não funciona nesse site

Comment: ueeee mas que estranho. Tipo, o console nao fecha. ele so encerra o programa, sem retornar o resultado. Coloquei ate um system("pause"); pra ter certeza.. ele realmente nao imprime aqui :s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acontece que você não inicializou os ponteiros. Tal como o proprio nome indica, eles são ponteiros, logo tem que apontar para algum local na memória que é onde são colocados os valores.

Logo quando faz:

```
*area = PI * pow(R, 2.0);
```

Está a dizer, no local de memoria onde o ponteiro `area` aponta, coloque este valor. Mas qual local é esse ? `area` não foi atribuído sequer, e por isso isto resulta em comportamento indefinido e potencialmente *segmentation fault*.

O próprio compilador lhe ajuda nesse sentido. Veja o que eu obtenho quando compilo o seu código:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
... main.c|14|warning: 'area' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
... main.c|14|warning: 'volume' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Como corrige ? Aloca espaço para o ponteiro, que seria o mais normal:

```
float *area = malloc(sizeof(float));
float *volume = malloc(sizeof(float));
```

Agora os ponteiros já apontam para um local válido na memória, mesmo que não tenham nenhum valor atribuído por si. Isto já irá fazer as atribuições seguintes funcionarem corretamente. Não se esqueça que deve de incluir `<stdlib.h>` para utilizar o `malloc`.

Outra alternativa, seria criar variáveis para a `area` e `volume` como valores e passar os seus endereços à função:

```
float area, volume;
...
calc_esfera(raio, &area, &volume);
//                ^------^-- aqui passa o endereço das variáveis no main
```

Esta ultima solução até seria preferível pois evita a alocação no *heap*, que causa mais fragmentação de memória e é mais lenta. Também evita com que tenha de preocupar em liberar a memória com `free` quando não precisar mais dela.

Comment: Entendi! muito obrigada, funcionou aqui. Ainda sou nova no assunto :).